# ImageButtonをクリックして別のActivityに移動したい

Tags: android, java

初歩的ではありますが、画面遷移に関して質問です。

`content_home.xml`のImageButtonをクリックした時に、新しいアクティビティ(`gender.java`)を開始したいです。

`content_home.xml`内の、ImageButtonにはidを`android:id="@+id/home_start"`としてあります。

よろしくお願いします。

**使用中のファイル**
home.java
content_home.xml
start_button.png
gender.java
content_gender.xml

訂正しました。

Comment: gender.javaを開くというのはActivityの開始という意味ですよね？

Comment: はい、そうです。分かりづらく申し訳ないです。

Comment: ちなみに、質問文に指摘をすると、'start_button.png'にはでは無くてImageButtonにはではありませんか？  start_button.pngはdrawableに配置されていると思うので、R.drawable.start_buttonになると思います。

Comment: 失礼しました。ImageButtonでは、android:id="@+id/home_start"、android:src="@drawable/start_button"、その他大きさなどの指定をしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activityを開始する為には、Intentと言うものを使います。
(home.javaからgender.javaに推移するということだとして)

```
ImageButton homeStart=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_start);
homeStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
     Intent i=new Intent(home.this,gender.class);
     startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

とすればActivityの開始ができます。

```
homeStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){});
```

とはButtonのクリックイベントを実装するための物です。ImageButtonでも同じように実装できます。
そして、`onClick(View v)`メソッドに処理を書きます。
(匿名クラス:Anonymous Classについても調べてみてください)
クリックイベントの実装方法はたくさんあるので調べてみてください。

---

`Intent`では、第一引数に`Context`を渡しています。
そして、第二引数に開始したい`Activity`の`Class`インスタンスを渡しています。
値を渡すなどのことはご自分で調べてみてください。

Comment: 教えて頂いた方法で正常に動作しました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: `getIntent()`で返却されるインテントは、その`Activity`が起動された際に呼び出されたときに利用されたインテントですので、その利用方法は不適切ですね。なんらかのパラメータを持っていた場合、それが意図せず引き継がれてしまいます。

Comment: @quesera2 そうだった！直しときます。